# Javascript TypeError: Type error when using IntersectionObserver() only in Safari

Tags: javascript, typeerror, intersection-observer

I can't figure out why Safari (13.0.2) is throwing a `TypeError: Type error` when using `IntersectionObserver()`. The other major browsers don't.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  const lazyImages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img"));

  if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
    const observerOptions = {
      root: document,
      rootMargin: '500px'
    }

    let lazyImageObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          let lazyImage = entry.target;
          lazyImage.src = lazyImage.getAttribute("data-lazyload-src");
          lazyImageObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
        }
      });
    }, observerOptions);

    lazyImages.forEach((lazyImage) => {
      lazyImageObserver.observe(lazyImage);
    });
  }
});
```

[image: Console error message]

Line 138 is `let lazyImageObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {`

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Also, regarding lazy-loading images, consider using the [`loading="lazy"` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-loading).

Comment: Concerning the error message: that's what I thought, but web developer shows no further information. Added a screenshot.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the line is `let lazyImageObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {`

Comment: I figured out, that if I leave out the `root` option in the `observerOptions` variable, the error goes away. Can you spot if there is something wrong with the syntax? 

Comment: The syntax is obviously fine, otherwise you couldn’t possibly have received a type error. Try `document.documentElement` or `document.body` instead of `document`. Does that work?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084306/intersectionobserver-not-working-in-safari-or-ios

Comment: Thanks! `document.body` works! Thanks again!

Comment: @ToE Okay, without having read the link Suraj has provided, this may be related to `document` being an `HTMLDocument`, but the other two being `HTMLElement`s each. Their prototype chains diverge after `Node`. Perhaps Safari can’t handle `HTMLDocument`s being `root`s in `IntersectionObserver`s.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntersectionObserver not working in Safari or iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084306/intersectionobserver-not-working-in-safari-or-ios)

Comment: @user4642212 Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @SurajRao, I tried user4642212's suggestion. Your link helped too. I don't know how to mark a comment as answer so I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to mark a comment as answer. Anyways, the suggestion in @user4642212's comment to use `document.body` instead of just `document`, works.

> Try `document.documentElement` or `document.body` instead of `document`

> This may be related to `document` being an `HTMLDocument`, but the other
> two being `HTMLElements` each. Their prototype chains diverge after
> `Node`. Perhaps Safari can’t handle `HTMLDocuments` being `roots` in
> `IntersectionObservers`.

Further reading provided by @SurajRao:
[IntersectionObserver not working in Safari or iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084306/intersectionobserver-not-working-in-safari-or-ios)