# Intersection observer not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events, intersection-observer

I am creating a simple navbar, which toggles background (via class ".nav-bg"), when it reaches end of first page (".hero"). It works 10/10 on Firefox/Chrome but doesn't work on Edge and Safari.
I can't figure out why.

Code:

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries =>{
    document.querySelector(".navbar").classList.toggle("nav-bg", entries[0].intersectionRatio < 0.1);
  }, {
    threshold: 0.1
   });
  
    observer.observe(document.querySelector(".hero"));
```

Comment: My be stupid question but do you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the beginning of your document?

Comment: @JohnRambo yes I have

Comment: I assume you already have tried: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084306/intersectionobserver-not-working-in-safari-or-ios)

Comment: Yes, still not working